# WaitUntilExists() method call

Tags: watin

I am relatively new to WatiN, but I would have thought the following line would have worked:

```
WebBrowser.Current.Table("grid").FindRow(value, columnNum).WaitUntilExists();
```

Currently it fails with the following exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I am guessing it has to do with the fact that the row in question has not been populated when the tet runs, and hence FindRow returns a null.

I have replaced the line with:

```
while (WebBrowser.Current.Table("grid").FindRow(value, columnNum) == null){}
```

which works - but would prefer to use a WatiN in built method (with a timeout).

Any ideas as to how to fix my first line of code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, WaitUntilExits() is different than WaitUntilIsNotNull ( which isn't a method :D )
You can probably use

```
WebBrowser.Current.Table("grid").FindRow(value, columnNum).WaitForComplete()
```

or

```
WebBrowser.Current.Table("grid").FindRow(value, columnNum).WaitUntilExists()
```

or

```
WebBrowser.Current.Table("grid").FindRow(value, columnNum).WaitUntil(attribute, value)
```

depending on what you need

Comment: Thanks for your answer, first two dont work :( The row itself does not exist, and I get the same error as presented in the question. Regarding the third piece of code, I dont think I have an attribute?

Comment: You might want to check first if the grid exists and then check for the specific row. 
WebBrowser.Current.Table("grid").WaitUntilExists()

Comment: Thanks for that. I do that already, but my grid is updated using ajax. This is not a problem for the rows created when the grid is created however it is a problem for the new rows created after the grid is created.

Comment: In my project there's a jqGrid and I'm using WebBrowser.Current.Div(identifier).WaitUntil("style", "display: none;"); to wait for the grid to load. Maybe you can find something similar..

Comment: If you have a 'value' in the row then you can use this value as the attribute, so: WebBrowser.Current.Table("grid").FindRow(value, columnNum).WaitUntil("value", value, 10000);
I would also suggest adding in a reasonable timeout.